# How to get toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9) with a nested function in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to make a unit test to check if a function is called a maximum of 9 times, the following code is an approximation of the real code:

```
function method1( event )
{
     method2(event);
}

function method3( event )
{
    input.value += event.key;
}

function method2(event)
{
    if (input.length < 9)
        method3(event);
}
```

As you can see the `method3()` is supposed to be executed only 9 times.

This is an approximation too of the Unit test I'm trying to do:

```
it("method3 should be called 9 times",() => {
spyOn(component.method1).and.callThrough;
spyOn(component.method2).and.callThrough;
spyOn(component.method3).and.callThrough;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    component.method1(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'1'}));
}

expect(component.method1).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.method2).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.method3).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.method3).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9); // with this the TEST DON'T PASS!
});
```

After execute the tests, the tests fails in the `toHaveBeenCalledTimes`, because it says: expected to be 9 times, it was called 0 times. I don't know if the reason is because it is a nested function.

Another thing that ocurred too, is that if I do: `expect(component.method1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(20)` instead of the (9) with the `method3`, that test PASS and it is called 20 times.

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `callThrough()` method of the spy.
`spyOn` makes a fake implementation of the method that you want to spy on. Therefore, your call to `method2` and `method3` never happens from fake `method1`.

`and.callThrough()` is used to call the actual method that you are spying on.

In your case, you are not calling the `callThrough()` method. Instead, you are just referring to `callThrough` function:

```
spyOn(component.method1).and.callThrough();//Make the actual call
```

**Why this assertion passes`spyOn(component.method1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(20)`?**

You are calling the `method1` 20 times in your `for` loop. **Note** that, you are calling the fake implementation 20 times and your test case asserts- Hey, is this method called 20 times?

Karma runner says - Yes, it's called 20 times (fake or real method call, it doesn't matter to him).

Comment: Really I need to check if method3 is called 9 times, that-s my question, I don't understand why you are answering that, your answer is not clearly with my needs. Thank you!

Comment: I'm calling callThrough, I don't understand why you said I'm not calling it.

Comment: I fix the error in the example code, that said spyOn instead of expect, thanks.